# NodeJS sqlite3 not returning variable (scope problem)

Tags: node.js, scope

This code returns undefined when it should be data from the Database. It is part of a class which has the variable this.database (an sqlite3 database). What have I done wrong?

```
    getData(chip_id) {
            let user_name;
            this.database.get("SELECT data FROM chips WHERE id=?",[chip_id],(err,row) => {
                    user_name = row.data;
            });
            return user_name;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Retrieving data from database is an asynchronous action and you should handle it with something like [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Change your function to this.

```
getData(chip_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let user_name;
    this.database.get("SELECT data FROM chips WHERE id=?", [chip_id], (err, row) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        user_name = row.data;
        resolve(user_name);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

and in the client side:

```
getData(id)
  .then(username => {
    // the username is ready to use
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle the error
  });
```

Reading these links also helps you a lot to start:

[Callbacks Vs Promises and basics of JS](https://medium.com/@theflyingmantis/callbacks-vs-promises-and-basics-of-js-80d3d1515e81)

[Getting to know asynchronous JavaScript: Callbacks, Promises and Async/Await](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)

[Converting callbacks to promises](https://zellwk.com/blog/converting-callbacks-to-promises/)